# Admob App showing default icon, even though my app got approved

Tags: admob

I recently made this app, and linked it to admob for the ads. When I first added my app to admob for approval, it showed the correct app icon. I've updated the app a few times since that day, and now it is showing the default icon.

[Default Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuVCm.png)

Even though the app is approved-

[Approved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtxL9.png)

Ads are successfully showing up on my ad, but is there something wrong?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that, must be a caching issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes time..

one time it took 7 days until we saw the app icon on Admob.

Don't worry about it.